# Using HeidiSQL with mysql select statement with "not like" does not work

Tags: mysql, sql

Ok guys, here's the story, I have a very simple query I'm trying to do and for the life of me I don't understand why it doesn't work.

I'm am using the streaming twitter feed to populate my database using keywords.  Now I want to filter out the retweets by using this query

```
select * from earthquake
where earthquake.Text not like '%RT%'
order by earthquake.Text
```

It returns "0 rows affected, 0 rows found", and yes there are thousands of retweets, so I know they exist.

I do the same query with the '%@%' and it finds thousands as expected, it almost seems that everything except 'RT' works.

Comment: This has nothing to do with HeidiSQL (a MySQL client)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try `NOT LIKE '%RT @%'`?
Is it possible that common word `xxxrtxxx` always contains in your Text field?

Comment: Ben, thanks, that's exactly the issue I didn't see.  This is a subquery of everything that contains "eaRThquake", which is of course everyone single one.  so your right I need to look for spaces infront and in back to solve my issue.  Thanks for the help everyone.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about mysql specifically, but is there a function like MSSQL's PatIndex() that you could use instead of not like?

Alternatively you could try something like this: (dont know if your db supports this syntax)

```
SELECT * FROM Earthquake
WHERE CASE WHEN Text LIKE '%RT%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END = 0
ORDER BY Text
```

I'd also advise checking your logic of looking for "RT" somewhere in the Text column to identify the stuff you don't want, because I'm surprised that "Not Like [expression]" apparently doesnt work.